# How can I get Chrome on Android to check SSL errors again with Appium?

Tags: android, perl, google-chrome, ssl, appium

Using Appium I need to bypass SSL-security error to access a page.
I used the `chromeOptions` `--ignore-certificate-errors` to do so and it seems to work.

However after disconnecting the device, I realized that Chrome didn't check for certificates errors anymore, using Appium but also using the device manually.
I have no idea why and how to get it back to normal (the option `don't-ignore-certificate-errors` doesn't exist since it's supposed to be the default comportment).

Here is my code for appium (in perl) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Appium;
use Test::More;

my $caps = {
    'deviceName'       => 'Nexus 4',
    'platformName'     => 'Android',
    'platformVersion'  => '4.2',
    'browserName'      => 'Chrome',
    'chromeOptions'    => {'args' => ['--ignore-certificate-errors']},
    };
my $appium = Appium->new(caps => $caps );
ok($appium, 'We have an Appium driver available!');
$appium->get('https://self-signed.badssl.com');
sleep(5);
$appium->quit;
done_testing;
1;
```

After investigating the issue I realized in Appium output that the browser is launched with `acceptSslCerts` even after removing the chromeOptions from my code.
Here is a part of Appium response I got when I try **not** to ignore certificate errors :

```
[debug] [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: -P, 5037, -s, 4df7f73251e5cfe5, shell, uiautomator, runtest, AppiumBootstrap.jar, -c, io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap, -e, pkg, com.android.chrome, -e, disableAndroidWatchers, false, -e, acceptSslCerts, false
```

Which seems like `acceptSslCerts will be on false, but then :

```
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"306888c4d7d59a322b3339e35410b142","status":0,"value":{"acceptSslCerts":true,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"browserName":"chrome","chrome":{"chromedr...
```

Why is this happening ?
Is there something wrong with my code ?

And how to get it back to normal ? (with Appium or manually)

Note: I already tried to clear the cache, the data, to force the app to stop and to reboot he device to no results...
This problem has been detected on Android 4.2 and confirmed with 5.0